# Passing reflect.Value to datastore.GetMulti in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I have a wrapper function `mypkg.GetStart` around [`datastore.GetMulti`](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-go/source/browse/appengine/datastore/datastore.go#250). The arguments of the wrapper function must be identical to `appengine.GetMulti`. I would like to get the first two entities of `dst`, for the sake of this example. My code currently looks like below but does not work. `datastore.GetMulti` produces the error `datastore: dst has invalid type`.

```
type myEntity struct {
    Val Int
}

keys := []*datastore.Key{keyOne, keyTwo, keyThree}
entities := make([]myEntity, 3)
mypkg.GetStart(c, keys, enities)
```

My `mypkg.GetStart` code is as follows:

```
func GetStart(c appengine.Context, keys []*datastore.Key, dst interface{}) error{
    v := reflect.ValueOf(dst)
    dstSlice := v.Slice(0, 2)
    return datastore.GetMulti(c, keys, dstSlice)
}
```

How can I make this work? Note this is a follow up question to [How to sub slice an interface{} that is a slice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22859547/how-to-sub-slice-an-interface-that-is-a-slice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work by adding `Interface()` to `dstSlice`:

```
func GetStart(c appengine.Context, keys []*datastore.Key, dst interface{}) error{
    v := reflect.ValueOf(dst)
    dstSlice := v.Slice(0, 2)
    return datastore.GetMulti(c, keys, dstSlice.Interface())
}
```